# Sum daily total by category in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi every one I have a database something like following:

```
TransactionID     DateTime        Amount      Country
-----------------------------------------------------
T123456           2013-05-01         100           US
T123457           2013-05-01         150           US
T123458           2013-05-01         200           CN
T123459           2013-05-01         250           CN
T123460           2013-05-02         250           TW
T123461           2013-05-02         350           ID
T123462           2013-05-02         200           TW
T123463           2013-05-02          50           ID
T123464           2013-05-02         250           TW
T123465           2013-05-03         450           TW
T123466           2013-05-03         350           ID
T123467           2013-05-03         200           TW
T123468           2013-05-03         150           CN
T123469           2013-05-03         350           US
```

Is it possible to use MSSQL to produce the following result?

```
DateTime        Amount      Country
-----------------------------------
2013-05-01         700        Total
2013-05-01         450           CN
2013-05-01         250           US
2013-05-02        1100        Total
2013-05-02         700           TW
2013-05-02         400           ID
2013-05-03        1500        Total
2013-05-03         650           TW
2013-05-03         350           ID
2013-05-03         350           US
2013-05-03         150           CN
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little UNION

```
SELECT u.DateTime, u.Amount, u.Country 
FROM (
SELECT DateTime, SUM(Amount) as Amount, Country
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DateTime, Country
UNION
SELECT DateTime, SUM(Amount) as Amount, 'Total' as Country
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DateTime) u
ORDER BY u.Datetime,
CASE WHEN u.Country = 'Total' THEN 0 else 1 END,
u.Country
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52b46/29)

Comment: the total must be on top of every day.

Comment: @DragonZelda you'll find ordered version of Gordon's answer in SqlFiddle

Comment: Also you can use ORDER BY clause without subquery http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52b46/8

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko You're right, as sum of all countries should be greater than sum by county. But if you have only one country for one day, does it just depend on the "order" of the union ? (mean first second part of union is the total ?)

Comment: Yes, you're right, if there is only one country in one day it does not work;) and +1 for a clarification

Answer (score 2):

You would normally do this with `rollup` or a similar clause:

```
select DateTime, sum(amount) as Amount, coalesce(country, 'Total')
from t
group by rollup(country), DateTime
```